How to Create a Grafana Dashboard for Open Alerts in Prometheus
I'm trying to create a Grafana dashboard that visualizes all the open alerts from Prometheus. Below is an example of an alert rule I'm working with. However, I'm having trouble displaying the 'description' of the triggered alert in the dashboard.
- alert: RootVolumeFillingUp
  expr: (1 - (node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/"} / node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/"})) * 100 > 90
  for: 10m
  labels:
    severity: critical
  annotations:
    summary: RootVolume is filling up.
    description: "The root volume usage on node {{`{{`}} $labels.instance {{`}}`}} is above 90% for more than 10 minutes."

Does anyone know how I can get the 'description' field from the alert to display in Grafana? Any guidance would be appreciated!
Tried using a plugin JSON API, but didn't work as expected.

This may not be exactly what you’re looking for, but we were able to build an “Active Alerts” Dashboard using the ALERTS Prometheus metric. By just filtering it to ALERTS{alertstate=“firing”}, we can get a list of all active alerts.
To visualize this data in a table, we need to also format the query to return the data in Table Format and an Instant vector (because we don’t care about past state in this example.)
Here’s an example with sensitive data redacted:

As for the description field, Alertmananger unfortunatley doesn’t store the alert description as a label in the ALERTS time series. This is probably because the description field could have very large cardinality, especially if threshold values are being interpolated into the string, and cardinality of a metric is one of the key determining factors in the performance of Prometheus (or Cortex as applicable.).
If you had a data source with the mapping from alert name to alert description, then you could add another query to get that relationship and then use the Join by Field transformation to put that all together. However, I’m not sure if/where that data would exist in your setup, so I’m going to leave this step as an exercise for the reader ;).
